# keyref in xsd not working

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, xsd

Below is a simplified version of my xsd and xml.
I am trying to check that each OrderedPart@rPartId has a valid match in Part@PartId.

All tools I have tried tell me this XML is valid against this xsd.
But second Order  should give error as 67 is not a valid Part@PartId.

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://localhost" xmlns="http://localhost" targetNamespace="http://localhost" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" >

    <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Order" type="OrderType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="Parts" type="PartType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:keyref name="dummy" refer="pNumKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="tns:OrderedPart" />
        <xs:field xpath="@rPartId"/>
    </xs:keyref>

    <xs:key name="pNumKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="tns:Part"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@PartId"/>
    </xs:key>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="OrderType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="OrderedPart" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="rPartId" type="xs:integer"/>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PartType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Part" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="PartId" type="xs:integer"/>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="KeyRefs.xsd"  xmlns="http://localhost" >
<Order>
    <OrderedPart rPartId="1"/>
</Order>
<Order>
    <OrderedPart rPartId="67"/> <!-- validation should give error -->
</Order>
<Parts>
    <Part PartId="1"/>
</Parts>
</root>
```

Suspect its something to do with the xPaths and/or namespaces in selectors.
Following input from other posts on this site I have played with the namespace combinations but cannot get this to work.

Any advice welcome.

(updates as OP seem to lose some of the XSD)

Comment: Seemed to have lost start of xsd:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem of your XSD is that you are not using selectors properly. **Selectors are relative to the element they belong to** as it is said in [XSD specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Identity-constraint_Definition_details):

> {selector} specifies a restricted XPath ([XPath]) expression relative
>   to instances of the element being declared.

For this reason you need to change your xpath selectors to `tns:Order/tns:OrderedPart` and `tns:Parts/tns:Part` in order to select the correct elements.

In addition, you are using `PartId` attribute as a key, however it is defined as an optional attribute. Usually this is not a desired behaviour as it is an error if the key is not present, so you can use `use="required"` in the attribute.

Comment: You are correct. Making changes you described to the selector fixed the issue. Thanks.